# Tensorflow Estimator: Cache bottlenecks

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, classification

When following the tensorflow image classification tutorial, at first it caches the bottleneck of each image:

[def: cache_bottlenecks())](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/a5105da43ae81267398bf0a2d12560edbced2715/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py#L433)

I have rewritten the training using tensorflow's `Estimator`. This really simplified all the code. However I want to cache the bottleneck features here.

Here is my `model_fn`. I want to cache the results of the `dense` layer so I can make changes to the actual training without having to compute the bottlenecks each time.

How can I accomplish that?

```py
def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
    is_training = mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN

    num_classes = len(params['label_vocab'])

    module = hub.Module(params['module_spec'], trainable=is_training and params['train_module'])
    bottleneck_tensor = module(features['image'])

    with tf.name_scope('final_retrain_ops'):
        logits = tf.layers.dense(bottleneck_tensor, units=num_classes, trainable=is_training)  # save this?

    def train_op_fn(loss):
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
        return optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())

    head = tf.contrib.estimator.multi_class_head(n_classes=num_classes, label_vocabulary=params['label_vocab'])

    return head.create_estimator_spec(
        features, mode, logits, labels, train_op_fn=train_op_fn
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

TF cannot work as you code. You should:

1. Export bottleneck to file from the raw net.
2. Use bottleneck result as input, use another net to train your data.

Comment: Can you post an example how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what @Feng said:

see [TFRecords and TFExamples](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tf_records#tfrecord_files_using_tfpython_io) and [Load Images](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images)

Something like this should work (untested):

```
# Serialize the data into two tfrecord files
tf.enable_eager_execution()
feature_extractor = ...
features_file = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter('features.tfrec')
label_file = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter('labels.tfrec')

for images, labels in dataset:
  features = feature_extractor(images)
  features_file.write(tf.serialize_tensor(features))
  label_file.write(tf.serialize_tensor(labels))
```

```
# Parse the files and zip them together
def parse(type, shape):
  _def parse(x):
    result = tf.parse_tensor(x, out_type=shape)
    result = tf.reshape(result, FEATURE_SHAPE)
    return result
  return parse

features_ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('features.tfrec')
features_ds = features_ds.map(parse(tf.float32, FEATURE_SHAPE), num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

labels_ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('labels.tfrec')
labels_ds = labels_ds.map(parse(tf.float32, FEATURE_SHAPE), num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip(features_ds, labels_ds)
ds = ds.unbatch().shuffle().repeat().batch().prefetch()...
```

You might also be able to do it using `Dataset.cache`, but I'm not 100% sure of the details.